# How to add values of particular column from One2many field in Odoo10

Tags: python-2.7, api, odoo, odoo-10

I have a One2many field and three fields inside the One2many field 'name','weight' and 'price'. I want that all values for 'weight' field added from multiple rows of One2many field.

My Python and XML Code is here:

**Python Code:**

```
class body_processing(models.Model):
    _name = 'body.processing'

     machine_weight_id = fields.One2many('machine.weight', 'machine_id', string='Weight Machine')

class machine_weight(models.Model):
    _name = 'machine.weight'


 @api.depends('weight','sum', 'machine_id')
    def _onchange_amount_weight(self):
        sum = 0.0
        vals = 0.0
        for line in self.machine_id:
            vals = line.weight + line.sum
            print"a", vals
            line.sum = line.vals
            print"b", line.sum
            line.sum += line.weight
            print"c", line.sum

machine_id = fields.Many2one('sale.pet', string='Machine Weight', ondelete='cascade', index=True,
                            copy=False)
pet = fields.Char()
weight = fields.Integer()
price = fields.Integer()
sum = fields.Integer('SUM', change_default = True, default= _onchange_amount_weight)
```

**XML Code:**

```
<group>
    <field name="machine_weight_id" style="width:630px">

        <tree editable="bottom">
            <field name="pet"/>
            <field name="weight"/>
            <field name="price"/>
            <field name="sum"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem i applied another function and i reached to print value of weight for every field. But how to access value weight from every row and add that values?

**My Function is here:**

```
@api.onchange('machine_weight_id')
    def _onchange_amount_weight(self):
        weight_obj = self.machine_weight_id
        print "a:", weight_obj
        for vals in weight_obj:
            print"v::", vals
            print "s", vals.weight
            print'sum', vals.weight
```